# React Native error "Attempt to get layout metrics from dirtied Yoga node."

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following error when running my app in ios simulator.

```
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to get layout metrics from dirtied Yoga node.
```

It goes away when I remove  from the following component. Does anyone know what's causing this? I would like to place elements within the view, but it's not letting me.

```
   class SearchModal extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (

      <View style={{ position: "absolute", left: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: 0.5, display: "flex"}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          value="Search"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you fixed this error? The same thing is happening to me.

Comment: I was trying to create a modal using position absolute. Ended up using <Modal> instead.

Comment: Having the same problem when I use position absolute. I think it's a regression in RN.

Comment: for me, `margin: auto` was causing this error

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue too. With my project ejected from Expo to Expo-Kit, the app crashes in debug mode but works fine in release mode. Usually it crashes when navigating.

**My Solution**:
 1. find `node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTShadowView.m`
 2. find `RCTAssert(!YGNodeIsDirty(node), @"Attempt to get layout metrics from dirtied Yoga node.")` (Mine is on line 170);
 3. Wrap it with `#if !RCT_DEBUG` and `#endif`, or comment it out.

Comment: This isn't as much of a solution as it is a work around. We still are unsure of a. where the error is occurring within the jsx structure of SearchModal and b. what is causing the error in itself.